# Is it always a best practice to write a function for anything that needs to repeat twice?

Tags: python, coding-style

Myself, I can't wait to write a function when I need to do something more than twice. But when it comes to things that only appear twice, it's a bit more tricky.

For code that needs more than two lines, I'll write a function. But when facing things like:

```
print "Hi, Tom"
print "Hi, Mary"
```

I'm hesitant to write:

```
def greeting(name):
    print "Hi, " + name

greeting('Tom')
greeting('Mary')
```

The second one seems too much, doesn't it?

---

But what if we have:

```
for name in vip_list:
    print name
for name in guest_list:
    print name
```

And here is the alternative:

```
def print_name(name_list):
    for name in name_list:
        print name

print_name(vip_list)
print_name(guest_list)
```

Things become tricky, no? It's hard to decide now.

What's your opinion about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rule of thumb for cost vs. savings for code re-use](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127118/rule-of-thumb-for-cost-vs-savings-for-code-re-use)

Comment: I treat `always` and `never` as red flags. There's a thing called "context", where the `always` and `never` rules, even if good in general, may not be that appropriate. Beware of software developers who deal in absolutes. ;)

Comment: In your last example you can do: `from itertools import chain; for name in chain(vip_list, guest_list): print(name)`.

Comment: @user16547 We call those 'sithware developers'!

Comment: From the Zen of Python by Tim Peters: `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
`

Comment: Also consider  if you want "damp code" or "dry code" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453235/what-does-damp-not-dry-mean-when-talking-about-unit-tests

Comment: Python is all about 'always' and 'never'. And don't tell me about *zen* -- Python never followed it.

Comment: @user16547 is right: "always" and "never" should be avoided at all costs. Instead, the one I like most is "consistent" :) .

Comment: @Bakuriu Or you could just do `for name in vip_list+guest_list`..?

Comment: Say that now you want to translate those greetings. In which case it's easier?

Comment: @OllieFord That creates a new list, so, during the iteration, you are using twice the memory. Surely you can use that if you know more or less how big the lists are going to be, but if you want a foolproof solution it's better to avoid the useless allocation of a new list.

Comment: @user16547 wait... do you *always* treat them as red flags?

Comment: Your function should be called `print_names`, not `print_name`.

Comment: "If it happens once, it may not happen again. If it happens twice it's likely it will happen the 3rd time" (not sure who said this but you get the point)

Comment: Anything that will repeated twice, will be repeated three times.

Comment: Anything that will be repeated twice, will be repeated three times.

Comment: I find myself programming from a readability standpoint rather than a "function by function" basis.  You have to weigh the effort you spend now versus the effort you spend in the future.

Comment: My personal policy is three or more lines of code that get repeated, not two or more.  And that's certainly not written in stone; as others have noted, you have to also be conscious of things like whether the repeated lines are actually all that related between the two spots they're used, whether the function can be named so that you don't have to read its definition to know what it does, etc.

Comment: But in cases where these aren't an issue, I'd *generally* go for at least three lines of code (or things like your `for` loops), because unless a lot of dots are coming into play or there's an `if` statement or something, two lines really do account for nothing.

Comment: Actually, you want something like (mapc #'print name-list), and then something like (mapc (lambda (l) (mapc #'print l)) (list vip-list guest-list)).  You can actually do things like this in C and C++, but it WILL baffle those of your coworkers who have never read the Wizard Book.

Comment: Anything that will be repeated twice, will be repeated three times.

Comment: Introducing a function mean that you cannot just follow the flow of the code down the page, but you need to - just like the CPU - jump to the function code, run that, jump back to continue.  It distrupts the reading flow and is the primary reason that method names needs to be good as it allows you to _assume_ what the method does without actually deciphering it.

Comment: Note that there are some cases in which greet(user) -- or even better, user.greet() -- make sense. What if some users need to be greeted in Hindi and others in Bengali? What if some users prefer a quick greeting at the top of the page, while others like a pop-up window warmly welcome them, while others hate all greetings? Isolating that code in a single place can be a huge help, but only if you think you'll need that isolation. If not, it's just a waste of space.

Comment: My rule of thumb, "write once, copy twice, refactor thrice". Not my original creation; I forget who said it, probably somewhere on Ward Christenson's  wiki http://c2.com/cgi/wiki

Answer (score 203):

Although it's one factor in deciding to split off a function, the number of times something is repeated shouldn't be the only factor.  It often makes sense to create a function for something that's only executed *once*.  Generally, you want to split a function when:

- It simplifies each individual abstraction layer.
- You have good, meaningful names for the split-off functions, so you don't usually need to jump around between abstraction layers to understand what's going on.

Your examples don't meet that criteria.  You're going from a one-liner to a one-liner, and the names don't really buy you anything in terms of clarity. That being said, functions that simple are rare outside of tutorials and school assignments.  Most programmers tend to err too far the other way.

Comment: This is the point I miss in RobertHarvey's answer.

Comment: Indeed.  I often split complex functions into inlined subroutines--no perf hit, but clean.  Anonymous scopes are good too.

Comment: There's also an issue of scope.  It probably doesn't make sense to write a **print_name(name_list)** function that a whole class or whole module can see, but it *might* (still a stretch in this case) make sense to make a local function within a function to clean up a few lines of repeated code.

Comment: Another point I'd maybe add is standardization. In the first example there's a greeting being done, and it could make sense to stick this in a function so that your're sure you're greeting both people the same. Especially considering the greeting may change in the future :)

Comment: Sometimes I wrap functionality that only occurs once in the code simply for unit testing purposes.  It makes it much easier and makes the tests more sane.

Comment: +1 just for *It often makes sense to create a function for something that's only executed once.* I was once asked how to design tests for a function that modeled the behavior of a rocket engine. The cyclomatic complexity of that function was in the 90s, and it wasn't a switch statement with 90 some cases (ugly, but testable). It instead was a convoluted mess written by engineers and was utterly untestable. My response was just that, that it was untestable and needed to be rewritten. They followed my advice!

Answer (score 106):

#### Only if the duplication is *intentional* rather than *accidental*.

Or, put another way:

#### Only if you would *expect* them to co-evolve in the future.

---

Here's why:

Sometimes, two pieces of code just *happen* to become the same even though they have nothing to do with each other. In that case you ***must*** resist the urge to combine them, because the next time someone performs maintenance on one of them, that person will *not* expect the changes to propagate to a previously-nonexistent caller, and that function may break as a result. Hence you have to only factor out code when it makes sense, not whenever it seems to reduce code size.

Rule of thumb:

If the code only returns new data and doesn't modify existing data or have other side effects, then it's very likely to be safe to factor out as a separate function. (I can't imagine any scenario in which that would cause a breakage without entirely changing the intended semantics of the function, at which point the function name or signature should change too, and you'd need to be careful in that case anyway.)

Comment: +1 I think that this is the most significant consideration.
No one refactors code expecting their change to be the last, so consider how your changes would affect future changes in the code.

Answer (score 60):

No, it's not always a best practice.

All other things being equal, linear, line-by-line code is easier to read than jumping around function calls.  A non-trivial function call always takes parameters, so you have to sort all that out and make mental contextual jumps from function call to function call.  Always favor better code clarity, unless you have a good reason for being obscure (such as obtaining necessary performance improvements).

So why is code refactored into separate methods then?  *To improve modularity.*  To collect *significant functionality* behind an individual method and give it a meaningful name.  If you're not accomplishing that, then you don't need those separate methods.

Comment: Code readability is the most important.

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer if you had not forgotten one of the top reasons for creating functions: to **create an abstraction** by giving a piece of functionality a good name. If you had added that point, it would be clear that linear, line-by-line code is *not* always easier to read than code using well-formed abstractions.

Comment: I agree with Doc Brown, code is not necessarily more readable line-by-line than when properly abstracted. Good function names make the high level functions VERY easy to read (because you're reading intent, not implementation) and low level functions easier to read because you are performing one task, exactly one task, and nothing but that task. This makes the function concise and precise.

Comment: `Why take the performance hit of a function call when you don't get any significant benefit by doing so?` What performance hit? In the general case small functions get inlined and the overhead is negligible for large functions. CPython probably doesn't inline, but nobody uses it for performance. I also question the `line by line code...` bit. It's easier if you're trying to simulate execution in your brain. But a debugger will do a better job, and trying to prove something about a loop by following its execution is like trying to prove a statement about integers by iterating over all of them.

Comment: @Doval raises a VERY valid point - when the code is compiled the function is placed inline (and duplicated) and therefore there is NO runtime performance hit, albeit there's a small one in compilation. That's not true for interpreted languages, but even so the function call is a minute proportion of the execution time.

Comment: @DocBrown: I modified my answer slightly to accomodate.

Comment: @JonStory: Functions are not always placed inline.

Comment: -1 The performance hit of calling another function is extraordinarily tiny. We routinely (and rightly) do things like instantiate large numbers of small classes and use polymorphism in the name of readability, considering their performance costs negligible compared to the developer time saved. Calling an additional function is much less expensive than even those examples. But the performance cost of calling a function is the most prominent reason in this answer.

Comment: @Kevin: You guys are entirely missing the point.  As small as the performance cost is, it's still larger than the benefit gained by refactoring the OP's example.  Quit obsessing over the performance aspect; it's entirely inconsequential to the main point that I am making.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If the performance aspect is inconsequential why do you lead with it in your answer?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I feel anyone that needs to ask this question doesn't have enough experience to not be swayed by arguments involving small-to-maybe-nonexistent performance overheads. This is the kind of question that sometimes gets asked by people that also wonder if they should compute everything in one large expression instead of assigning intermediate results to save some memory or assembly instructions. I feel the answer would be much better if you didn't even mention performance and led with your points about modularity and clarity.

Comment: Since you guys seem to insist on obsessing over the performance comment, I've deleted the relevant paragraph.

Answer (score 25):

In your particular example making a function may seem overkill; instead I would ask the question: is it possible that this particular greeting will change in the future? How so?

Functions are not simply used to wrap up functionality and ease reuse, but also to ease modification. If requirements change, copy-pasted code will need to be hunted down and changed manually, while with a function the code needs to be modified only once.

Your example would benefit from this not via a function - since the logic is nearly non-existent - but possibly a `GREET_OPENING` constant. This constant could then be loaded from file so that your program would be easily adaptable to different languages, for example. Note that this is a crude solution, a more complex program would probably need a more refined way to track i18n, but again it depends on requirements vs work to do.

It's all about possible requirements in the end, and planning things in advance to ease your future self's job.

Comment: Using a GREET_OPENING constant assumes all possible greetings are in the same order.  Being married to someone whose mother tongue does almost everything opposite of English makes me leery of this assumption.

Answer (score 22):

Personally I have adopted the rule of three - which I'll justify by calling [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). If I need to do something once I'll write that code, twice I may just copy / paste (yes I just admitted to copy/paste!) because I ain't gonna need it again, but if I need to do the same thing again then I'll refactor and extract that chunk into it's own method, I've demonstrated, to myself, that I **will** need it again.

I agree with what Karl Bielefeldt and Robert Harvey have said and my interpretation of what they're saying is that the overriding rule is readability. If it makes my code easier to read then consider creating a function, keep in mind things like [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and [SLAP](https://masihjesus.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/single-level-of-abstraction/). If I can avoid having changing level of abstraction in my function then I find that easier to manage in my head, so not jumping between functions (if I can't understand what the function does simply by reading it's name) means fewer switches in my mental processes.
Likewise not having to switch context between functions and inline code such as `print "Hi, Tom"` works for me, in this case I *might* extract a function `PrintNames()` **iff** the rest of my overall function were mostly function calls.

Comment: The c2 wiki has a good page on the Rule of Three: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RuleOfThree

Answer (score 13):

It's seldom clear-cut, so you need to weigh options:

- Deadline (fix burning server room ASAP)
- Code readability (may influence choice either way)
- Shared logic's level of abstraction (related to above)
- Re-use requirement (i.e. is having exact same logic important, or just convenient right now)
- Difficulty of sharing (here is wher python shines, see below)

In C++, I usually go by the rule of three (i.e. the third time I need the same thing, I refactor it into a properly sharable piece), but with experience it's easier to make that choice initially as you know more about the scope, software & domain you're working with.

However, in Python it is fairly light-weight to reuse, rather than repeat, logic. More so than in many other languages (at least historically), IMO.

So, consider just re-using the logic locally, for instance by by creating a list from local arguments:

```
def foo():
    for name_list in (vip_list, guest_list): # can be list of tuples, for many args
        for name in name_list:
            print name
```

You can use a tuple of tuples, and split it directly into the for-loop, if you need several arguments:

```
def foo2():
    for header, name_list in (('vips': vip_list), ('people': guest_list)): 
        print header + ": "
        for name in name_list:
            print name
```

or make a local function (maybe your second example is that), which makes the logic re-use explicit but also clearly shows that print_name() isn't used outside the function:

```
def foo():
    def print_name(name_list):
        for name in name_list:
            print name

    print_name(vip_list)
    print_name(guest_list)
```

Functions are preferable especially when you need to abort the logic in the middle (i.e. use return), as break or exceptions might clutter things unnecessarily.

Either is superior to repeating the same logic, IMO, and also less cluttering than declaring a global/class function that is only used by one caller (albeit twice).

Comment: I posted [a similar comment](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/269882/is-it-always-a-best-practice-to-write-a-function-for-anything-that-needs-to-repe#comment550202_269890) about the *scope* of the new function before I saw this answer.  I'm glad there's an answer addressing that aspect of the question.

Comment: +1 -- this is maybe not the sort of answer that the OP is looking for, but, at least regarding the kind of question that he asked, I think this is the most sensible response. This is the kind of thing that will probably be baked into the language for you, somehow.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: Thanks for the vote! :) I've added some considerations to make the answer more complete.

Answer (score 9):

All best-practices have a particular reason, which you can refer to in order to answer such a question.
You should always avoid ripples, when one potential future change implies changes to other components as well.

So in your example:
If you assume that you have a standard greeting and you want to ensure it's the same for all people, then write

```
def std_greeting(name):
    print "Hi, " + name

for name in ["Tom", "Mary"]:
    std_greeting(name)   # even the function call should be written only once
```

Otherwise, you'd have to pay attention and change the standard greeting at two places, if it happens to change.

If, however, the "Hi" is the same just by accident and changing one of the greetings does not necessarily result in changes for the other, then keep them separate. Therefore, keep them separate if there are logical reasons to believe, that the following change is more likely:

```
print "Hi, Tom"
print "Hello, Mary"
```

For your second part, to decide how much to "package" into functions probably depends on two factors:

- keep blocks small for readability
- keep blocks large enough so that changes occur in only few blocks. Not need to cluster too much as it's hard to track the calling pattern.

Ideally, when a change occurs you will think "I have to change most of the following block" and not "I have to change code *somewhere* inside a large block".

Comment: Just a stupid nitpicking considering your loop - if there really need to be only a handful of hard-coded names to iterate over, and we don't expect them to change, I'd argue that it's a bit more legible to not use a list.

`for name in "Tom", "Mary": std_greeting(name)`

Comment: Well, to continue one could say a hard-coded list is not going to appear in the middle of code and will be a variable anyway :) But right, I actually forgot that you can skip the braces there.

Answer (score 5):

The most important aspect of named constants and functions isn't so much that they reduce the amount of typing, but rather that they "attach" the different places where they are used.  With regard to your example, consider four scenarios:

1. It's necessary to change both greetings in the same way, [e.g. to `Bonjour, Tom` and `Bonjour, Mary`].
2. It's necessary to change one greeting but leave the other as it is [e.g. `Hi, Tom` and `Guten Tag, Mary`].
3. It's necessary to change both greetings differently [e.g. `Hello, Tom` and `Howdy, Mary`].
4. Neither greeting ever needs to be changed.

If it's never necessary to change either greeting, it won't really matter which approach is taken.  Using a shared function will have the natural effect that changing any greeting will change them all the same way.  If all greetings should change the same way, that would be a good thing.  If they shouldn't, however, then each person's greeting will have to be coded or specified separately; any work done making them use a common function or specification will have to be undone (and would have been better not done in the first place).

To be sure, it's not always possible to predict the future, but if one has reason to believe that it's more likely that both greetings will need to change together, that would be a factor in favor of using common code (or a named constant); if one has reason to believe that it's more likely that one or both might need to change so that they differ, that would be a factor against trying to use common code.

Comment: I like this answer because (for this simple example at least), you could almost calculate the choice via some game theory.

Comment: @RubberDuck: I think far too little attention is generally given to the question of what things should or should not be "aliased"--in many regards, and would expect that the two most common causes of bugs are (1) believing things are aliased/attached when they aren't, or (2) changing something without realizing that other things are attached to it.  Such issues arise in the design of both code and data structures, but I don't recall having ever seen much attention given to the concept.  Aliasing doesn't generally matter when there's only one of something, or if it will never change, but...

Comment: @RubberDuck: ...if there are two of something and they match, it's important to know whether changing one should leave the value of the other one constant, or should keep the *relationship* constant (meaning the value of the other would change).  I often see great weight given to the advantages of keeping *values* constant, but far less weight given to the importance of *relationships*.

Comment: I completely agree. I was just musing on how conventional wisdom says to DRY it up, but *statistically*, it is more likely that the repeated code will later not be repeated code. You've basically got 2 to 1 odds.

Comment: @RubberDuck: That I give two scenarios where detachment is important and one where attachment is better doesn't say anything about the relative likelihoods of the various scenarios occurring.  What's important is recognizing when two pieces of code match "by coincidence" or because they have the same fundamental meaning.  Further, when there are more than two items, additional scenarios arise where one end up wanting to make one or more differ from the others, but still change two or more in identical fashion; also, even if an action is only used in one place...

Comment: ...one may expect to use that same action elsewhere and intend that all usages should always match.  Consequently, it may be worth breaking out a short piece of code into its own method even if it will (at least for awhile) only be used once.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should have a reason to create a procedure. There are a number of reasons to create a procedure. The ones that I think are most important are:

1. abstraction
2. modularity
3. code navigation
4. update consistency
5. recursion
6. testing

### Abstraction

A procedure can be used to abstract a general algorithm from the details of particular steps in the algorithm. If I can find a suitably coherent abstraction, this helps me to structure the way I think about what the algorithm does. For example, I can design an algorithm that works on lists without having to necessarily consider the list representation.

### Modularity

Procedures can be used to organise code into modules. The modules can often be treated separately. For example, built and tested separately.

Well designed module typically capture some coherent meaningful unit of functionality. Therfore they can often be owned by different teams, replaced completely with an alternative or reused in a different context.

### Code Navigation

In large systems, finding the code associated with a particular system behaviour can be challenging. Hierarchical organisation of the code within libraries, modules and procedures can help with this challenge. Particularly if you try to a) organise functionality under meaningful and predictable names b) place the procedures relating to similar functionality near each other.

### Update Consistency

In large systems it can be challenging to find all the code that needs to be changed to achieve a particular change in behavior. Using procedures to organise the functionality of the program can make this easier. In particular, if each bit of functionality of your program appears only once and in a cohesive group of procedures it is less likely (in my experience) that you will miss somewhere you should have updated or make an inconsistent update.

Note that you should organise procedures based on the functionaility and abstractions in the program. Not based on whether two bits of code happen to be the same at the moment.

### Recursion

Using recursion requires that you create procedures

### Testing

You can usually test procedures independently of each other. Testing different parts of the body of a procedure independently is more difficult, because you typically have to execute the first part of the procedure before the second part. This observation also often applies to other approaches to specifying/verifying programs behavior.

### Conclusion

Many of these points relate to the comprehensibility of the program. You could say that procedures are a way to create a new language, specific to your domain, with which to organise, write, and read, about the problems and processes in your domain.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of the cases you give seem worth refactoring.

In both cases, you are performing an operation which is expressed clearly and succinctly, and there is no danger of an inconsistent change being made.

I recommend you always look for ways to isolate code where:

1. There is an identifiable, meaningful task which you could separate out, **and**
2. **Either**

   a. the task is complex to express (taking into account the functions available to you) **or**

   b. the task is performed more than once, and you need a way of making sure it is changed the same way in both places,

If condition 1 is not satisfied then you will not find the right interface for the code: if you try to force it you will end up with loads of parameters, multiple things you want to return, lots of contextual logic, and will quite possibly be unable to find a good name. Try documenting the interface you are thinking of first, it's a good way of testing the hypothesis that it's the right bundling of functionality and comes with the added bonus that when you write your code, it's already specced and documented!

2a is possible without 2b: sometimes I have taken code out the flow even when I know it only gets used once, simply because moving it elsewhere and replacing it with a single line means that the context in which it is called is suddenly much more readable (especially if it's an easy concept which the language happens to make difficult to implement). It's also clear when reading the extracted function where the logic begins and ends and what it does.

2b is possible without 2a: The trick is having a feel for what sort of changes are more likely. Is it more likely that your company policy will change from saying "Hi" everywhere to "Hello" all the time or that your greeting changes to a more formal tone if you're sending a demand for payment or an apology for a service outage? Sometimes it might be because you're using an external library you're not sure about and want to be able to swap that for another one quickly: the implementation might change even if the functionality doesn't.

Most often, though, you'll have some a mixture of 2a and 2b. And you'll have to use your judgment, taking into account the business value of the code, the frequency it gets used, whether it's well-documented and understood, the state of your test suite, etc.

If you notice the same bit of logic used more than once, by all means you should take the opportunity to consider refactoring. If you're beginning new statements more than `n` indentation levels in in most languages, that's another, slightly less significant trigger (pick a value of `n` you're comfortable with for your given language: Python might be 6, for instance).

So long as you're giving thought to these things and taking down the big spaghetti-code monsters, you should be fine - don't spend so long worrying about how fine-grained your refactoring needs to be that you don't have time for things like tests or documentation worked up about. If it does need doing, time will tell.

Answer (score 3):

In general I agree with Robert Harvey, but wanted to add a case to split up a functionality into functions. To improve readability. Consider a case:

```
def doIt(smth,smthElse)
    for x in getDataFromSomething(smth,smthElse):
        if not check(x,smth):
            continue
        process(x,smthElse)
        store(x)
```

Even though those function calls are not used anywhere else, there is significant gain in readability if all 3 functions are considerably long and have nested loops etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard and fast rule that must be applied, it will depend on the actual function that would be used. For simple name printing I would not use a function but if it is a maths sum that would be a different story. You then would create a function even if it only gets called twice, this is to ensure that the maths sum is always the same if ever changed. In another example if you are doing any form of validation you would use a function, so in your example if you needed to check the name is longer than 5 characters you would use a function to ensure the same validations are always done.

So I think you answered your own question when you stated "For codes that need more than two lines, I'll got to write a func". In general you would be using a function but you must also use your own logic to determine if there is any kind of value add from using a function.

Answer (score 2):

I have come to believe something about refactoring that I haven't seen mentioned here, I know there are a lot of answers here already, but I think this is new.

I've been a ruthless refactorer and a strong believer in DRY since before the terms arose. Mostly it's because I have trouble keeping a large codebase in my head and partly because I enjoy DRY coding and I do not enjoy anything about C&P coding, in fact it's painful and terribly slow for me.

The thing is, insisting on DRY has given me a lot of practice in some techniques that I rarely see others use.  A lot of people insist that Java is difficult or impossible to make DRY, but really they just don't try.

One example from a long time ago that's somewhat similar to your example.  People tend to think java GUI creation is hard.  Of course it is if you code like this:

```
Menu m=new Menu("File");
MenuItem save=new MenuItem("Save")
save.addAction(saveAction); // I forget the syntax, but you get the idea
m.add(save);
MenuItem load=new MenuItem("Load")
load.addAction(loadAction)
```

Anyone who thinks this is just crazy is absolutely right, but it's not Java's fault--code should never be written this way.  These method calls are functions intended to be wrapped in other systems.  If you can't find such a system, build it!

You obviously can't code like that so you need to step back and look at the problem, what is that repeated code actually doing?  It's specifying some strings and their relationship(a tree) and joining the leaves of that tree to actions.
So what you really want is to say:

```
class Menu {
    @MenuItem("File|Load")
    public void fileLoad(){...}
    @MenuItem("File|Save")
    public void fileSave(){...}
    @MenuItem("Edit|Copy")
    public void editCopy(){...}...
```

Once you've defined your relationship in some way that is succinct and descriptive then you write a method to deal with it--in this case you iterate over the methods of the class passed in and build a tree then use that to build your Menus and Actions as well as (obviously) display a menu. You'll have no duplication, and your method is reusable... and probably easier to write than a large number of menus would have been, and if you actually enjoy programming, you had a LOT more fun.  This isn't hard--the method you need to write is probably less lines than creating your menu by hand would be!

Thing is, in order to do this well you need to practice, a lot.  You need to get good at analyzing exactly what unique information is in the repeated parts, extract that information and figure out how to express it well.  Learning to use tools like string parsing and annotations helps a lot.  Learning to be really clear about error reporting and documentation is very important as well.

You get "Free" practice simply by coding well--heck chances are that once you get good at it you'll find that coding something DRY (including writing a reusable tool) is faster than copying and pasting and all the errors, duplicated errors and difficult changes that type of coding causes.

I don't think I'd be able to enjoy my job if I didn't practice DRY techniques and building tools as much as I could.  If I had to take a cut in pay not to have to do copy and paste programming, I'd take it.

So my points are:

- Copy & Paste costs more time unless you don't know how to refactor well.
- You learn to refactor well by doing it--by insisting on DRY even in the most difficult and trivial of cases.
- You are a programmer, if you need a small tool to make your code DRY, build it.

Answer (score 1):

As a corollary to @DocBrown's comment to @RobertHarvey about using functions to create abstractions: if you can't come up with an adequately informative function name that isn't significantly more concise or clearer than the code behind it, you are not abstracting much. Absent any other other good reason for making it a function, there is no need to do so.

Also, a function name rarely captures its full semantics, so you may have to go check its definition, if it isn't commonly-enough used to be familiar. Particularly in other than a functional language, you may need to know if it has side-effects, what errors may occur and how they are responded to, its time complexity, whether it allocates and/or frees resources, and whether it is thread-safe.

Of course, we are by definition considering only simple functions here, but that goes both ways - in such cases, inlining is not likely to add complexity. Furthermore, the reader probably will not realize that it is a simple function until he looks. Even with an IDE that hyperlinks you to the definition, the visual jumping around is an impediment to understanding.

Generally speaking, recursively factoring code into more, smaller functions will eventually bring you to the point where the functions no longer have independent meaning, because as the code fragments they are made from get smaller, those fragments get more of their meaning from the context created by the surrounding code. As an analogy, think of it like a picture: if you zoom in too closely, you can't make out what you are looking at.

Comment: Even if is the simplest of statements wrapping it in a function should make it more readable.  There are times when wrapping it in a function is overkill but if you can't come up with a function name that is more concise and clear than what the statements are doing that is probably a bad sign.  Your negatives for using functions aren't really a big deal imo.  The negatives for inlining are a much bigger deal.  Inlining makes it harder to read, harder to maintain, and harder to reuse.

Comment: @pllee : I have presented reasons why factoring into functions becomes counter-productive when taken to extremes (note that the question is specifically about taking it to extremes, not the general case.) You have offered no counter-argument to these points, but merely claim it 'should' be different. Writing that the naming problem is 'probably' a bad sign is not an argument that it is avoidable in the cases considered here (my argument, of course, is that it *is* at least a warning - that you  may have reached the point of merely abstracting for its own sake.)

Comment: I mentioned 3 negatives of inlining not sure where I merely claim it "should be different".  All I am saying is that if you can't come up with a name your inline is probably doing too much.  Also I think you are missing a big point here about even tiny once used methods.  Tiny well named methods exist so you don't have to know what the code trying to do (no need to IDE jump).  For example even the simple statement of ` if(day == 0 || day == 6) ` vs ` if(isWeekend(day))` becomes easier to read and mentally map.  Now if you need to repeat that statement `isWeekend` becomes a no brainer.

Comment: @pllee You claim that it is "probably a bad sign" if you cannot find a significantly shorter, clearer name for almost every repeated code fragment, but that appears to be a matter of faith - you give no supporting argument (to make a general case, you need more than examples.)  isWeekend does have a meaningful name, so the only way it could fail my criteria is if it is neither significantly shorter nor significantly clearer than its implementation. By arguing that you think it is the latter, you are asserting that it is not a counter-example to my position (FWIW, I have used isWeekend myself.)

Comment: I gave an example where even a single line statement can be more readable and I gave negatives of inlining code. That is my humble opinion and all I am saying and no I am not arguing against or talking about the "unnameable method".  I am not really sure what is so confusing about that or why you think I need a "theoretical proof" for my opinion.  I exampled improved readability.  Maintenance is harder because if the code hunk changes it needs to in N number of spots (read about DRY).  It is obviously harder to reuse unless you think copy paste if a viable way of reusing code.

Comment: @pllee Nobody is claiming that small functions are not useful. The question is about the dogmatic claim that it is *always* right to make a function for *anything* repeated. Examples of or arguments for the former do *not* establish the latter, because it is universally quantified. The first sentence of your first reply looks like a claim that the dogma is right. If, instead of saying it 'should' be so, you meant to say that you think it is almost always feasible and useful to do this, then I would say I think you are overestimating the benefit in trivial cases such as those in the question.

Comment: No it is not dogmatic not at all, I really have no clue what you are arguing about.   I said `should` I did not say `always`.  Heck I even upvoted the comment about `always` and `never` before reading your answer.  I also even mentioned it can be overkill.  If you have any rebuttals or comments on the actual words written in my first comment I would love to hear them, I am always happy to learn.

Comment: @pllee You have just added another bit of confusion. You write " I said should I did not say always", but if you read my post, you will see that I actually wrote that the *question*, not you, says 'always' - the question, of course, being the text at the top of the page, towards which everything else on this page should be directed. So your first sentence in your last post says that the question is not dogmatic at all, but that seems at odds with what follows, where you argue that your position is more pragmatic than the one of the question - did you mean to say your view is not dogmatic?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's a good idea to split something into a function of it improves the readability of your code, Or, if the part being oft repeated is somehow core to the system.
In the above example, If you needed to greet your users depending on the locale, then it would make sense to have a separate greeter function.